# Microservices: BFF (Backend For Frontend) vs Aggregator Service Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices

I've been studying microservices (i have started about some weeks ago) and when i saw the instructor saying about process aggregator pattern, then i was thinking if its same ideia of BFFs?

Thanks guys!

Im expecting to understand the main difference, in case that there is a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have the same outcome, and that is to create an abstraction over several backend processes in order to combine multiple processes into a single facade (facade pattern).  The BFF is explicitly about creating a facade for a front-end, while aggregator (or facade) pattern is more generic and is not explicitly for a UI.  Thus this is really different names for the same old [gof facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) with new branding.